# Como puedo Usar El Espacio (Spacebar) en el comando "CHOICE"

Tags: windows, batch

*NECESITO UNA SCRIPT PARA QUE EL COMADO 'CHOICE' **DETECTE LA TECLA ESPACIO***
Estoy haciendo un lenguaje de programación el programa de este nuevo lenguaje lo estoy haciendo con batch. Lo se no es el mejor pero soy muy avanzado en ese "lenguaje" Lamentablemente no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. Busque foros en ingles o post... pero nada. Agradezco su ayuda **GRACIAS**

Comment: Podrías especificar un poco más concreto tu problema? Ya tienes algo de código (en el alrededor donde quieres detectar la tecla espacio)?

Comment: Es tipo con un comando basico. Por ej: Choice /c 1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm /n /m "^>" (ovio ya se poner la Ñ en el choice) solo falta espacio

Answer (score 0):

No puedes

La [documentación](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc732504%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) de Microsoft indica:

> Valid choices include a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and extended ASCII characters
>   (128-254)

lo que deja al espacio (ASCII 32) fuera del rango de valores permitidos.

Comment: Y no puede ser con otro comando que no sea choice u con un programa auxiliar?